# Null Pointer on Autowired Service Object in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am learning Spring MVC, and am trying to troubleshoot an issue with an `@Autowired` Service object. I have the following annotation:

```
@Autowired
private UserServiceBLInt userService;
```

This is within the context of a `Controller` class, and I get a `NullPointerException` when using the `userService` object. Nowhere in the class am I manually instantiating the `userService` object, since my understanding is that for `@Autowired` to work, I have to let spring be responsible for creating the object.

My suspicion is that in the spring configuration file, the `component-scan base-package` declared incorrectly, so Spring doesn't know where to find the classes.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.service.**" />
```

The `UserServiceBLInt` is in `com.app.service.int`
The concrete implementation is in `com.app.service.impl`

Is the `**` notation correct?

Comment: Show us your context configuration and the classes involved in this particular case.

Comment: If you suspect "**" is the culprit why not try without it?

Comment: Is your service class `@Service` annotated?

Comment: @rc, I tried it with a single *, but not yet with removing it alltogether

Comment: @araknoid, should the interface or the implementation be annotated with @service?

Comment: The implementation should be annotated with `@Service`

Answer (score 0):

The example in the [Spring reference doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) does not use `.**`:

```
<beans>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.acme"/>
</beans>
```

So most likely, this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the .** ind base package declartion. just specify the package name whose Bean you want to autowire by Spring, you can use comma separated values for package name as well.